# What is the current state of the muon $g-2$ experiment at Fermilab?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

What is the current state of the [muon $g-2$ experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon_g-2) at Fermilab? The last time I read about it, the $g-2$ factor was only correct upto 8 decimal places as calculated by QED which was less than that measured for the electron. Has the experiment been refined since?

Comment: A recent review mentions the 3.3 sigma discrepancy: http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-g-2-muon-anom-mag-moment.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that muon g-2 is finally in the news : https://www.quantamagazine.org/muon-g-2-experiment-at-fermilab-finds-hint-of-new-particles-20210407